# Jquery: Detecting if a tickbox is selected

Tags: jquery

Why does this simple if statement always say the box is unchecked?

```
  $("#x").prop('checked',true);
//$("#x").prop('checked',false);

 if ($("#x").checked) {
     alert("Checbox is checked");
 } else {
     alert("Checkbox is not checked");
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4Tmu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.checked` is not a jquery property but a DOM element property.

You have to use `.is(':checked')` or `.prop('checked')`

```
$("#x").prop('checked',true);
//$("#x").prop('checked',false);

if ($("#x").is(':checked')) {
     alert("Checbox is checked");
 } else {
     alert("Checkbox is not checked");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe in jQuery you could use the `:checked` selector, but in your case I would just use native. From what it looks like in your code is that you are using a mix of native and jQuery. I'm not sure if it's correct though.

Try this:

```
var x = document.getElementById('x');
x.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');

if (x.checked) {
    // Checkbox is checked
} else {
    // Checkbox is not checked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`checked` is a DOM element property so use it on DOM elements:

```
$("#x")[0].checked
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4Tmu/13/

otherwise uses:

```
$("#x").is(':checked')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4Tmu/16/

Answer (score -2):

this is my answer, tested:

```
$("#x").attr('checked',true);
//$("#x").prop('checked',false);

if ($("#x").attr("checked")) {
     alert("Checbox is checked");
} else {
     alert("Checkbox is not checked");
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I believe it was down-voted because of the lack of quality in the answer. You see, all you did was change a few things without explaining why his code wasn't working as expected. Sure, your provided a solution to his problem, but ultimately it didn't help him understand the problem so he may run into a similar problem in the future and not have access to S.O. and ultimately not know how to solve his problem.

Comment: @JasonYang while your code works as-is, it breaks under other conditions because you are using `.attr()` instead of `.prop()`. In current versions of jQuery `.attr()` gets/sets the default state of the checkbox, while `.prop()` gets/sets the current state. Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4Tmu/28/) for an example.

Comment: think you very much @winterblood